# Rebuilding Sql Server indexes name invalidate the hardcoded value in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In EF Context file,i have hard coded key name/index name in `OnModelCreating`. DBA rebuilt those indexes/keys with different names.  Do i have to update those reference in code again ? or is there any other approach ?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){

modelBuilder.Entity<Customert>(entity =>
{
  entity.HasKey(e => e.custId)
        .HasName("PK__cust__4E739DAA");
}

}
```

Comment: Why did you specify the key name in the first place, if the DBA can change it? Why not use a *proper* name instead of hard-coding an autogenerated (ie random) one?

Comment: BTW rebuilding an index won't change its name. The DBA either renamed it or dropped and recreated it.

Comment: DBA does changes their name too while rebuilding, not under my control. can i ignore hasName line ? why this property exist ?  I don't want to hard-coded anything.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can use `Key` attribute directly on entity property, for instance

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
}
```

[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: "PK__cust__4E739DAA" is hardcoded. Column name is not a issue.

Comment: @user6069595 don't hard-code auto-generated names. Use proper names that don't force DBAs to rename them'